# Can we put some documents which are not listed as required documents for jobs

Tags: job, application-cover-letter, non-tenure

I am going to apply for non-tenure tack academic position and I have already prepared all documents. They did not list Cover Letter as a required document. I would like to know whether it is necessary or not to put this document in my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cover letter is probably fine, provided that the application system will accept it. Some online systems can be strict about what they will accept. If they want a SoP (Statement of Purpose), they probably expect to see there what you might otherwise put in a cover letter.

But avoid including a lot of unasked for documents. The institution knows what it wants to see and wants all applications to be similar in structure just to ease the work of evaluation.

In required documents you can sometimes point to the existence of other things that people might want to see if you are seriously under consideration. But wait until you are asked to send those extra things.

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, ask.

Buffy's advice is good, but I have previously benefited from sending a testimonial when such things weren't requested. I wouldn't include extra documents unsolicited, but if there are other things that you would like to include, contact the people handling the recruitment and ask if it's OK.